# Access Angular 2 component from another module / window

Tags: angular

I am looking to access an Angular 2 component from another module as well as the window object. The window object would only be used for playing around in the browser console not actually for production (fyi). I was thinking I could 'export default class MyComponent' but that doesn't seem to work. How would I access the instantiated MyAppComponent class from another module / the window?

```
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <script>
        System.import('ang').then(function (ang) {
            window.ang = ang;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

...

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: `<h1>Hello {{ count }}</h1><br>`
})

class MyAppComponent {
    public count: number;

    constructor() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public increment(): void {
        this.count++;
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

Then want to do something like this:

```
ang.increment();
```

Comment: May I suggest accepting @Jeff Fairley answer, it worked for me, with Angular 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution, which leverages some Angular internals. I can verify that this works in Angular 6, but of course, be aware that YMMV.

Also worth nothing, TypeScript isn't quite happy with this, so in my code, I had to cast things here and there. I've removed the casts here for code clarity.

```js
const debugElement: DebugElement = window.ng.probe(document.querySelector('my-app'))
const app: MyAppComponent = debugElement.componentInstance;
app.increment();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from bootstrap callback:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
]).then((app)=> {
  window.app = app
});
```

Then call from console

```
app.instance.myMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Your component global variable

```
constructor() {
    window['AppComponent'] = {Appcomponent: {all:this}};
 }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjaaen

[image]